# I want to use for each loop in angular js.I donot know how

Tags: javascript, angularjs, for-loop

I want to use for each loop in angular js.

I am new in using augular js .

Kindly suggest me the method for working with angular js.

Suggestions and correction are welcome.

Comment: Please... at least do a google search before posting new questions. Angular has decent documentation. read [ask]

Comment: I do google search,but I am not aware how to ask question in so.
thanks for your suggestion and link

Comment: welcome to SO ..please read the FAQ section before asking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is code sample to use angular.forEach() for iterating in angularjs.

if you have any other issue then you can ask.

```
angular.forEach($scope.tasks, function (task, index) {
    if (task.isCompleted) {
        task.showTask = true;
    }
});
```

use iteration through foreach loop.

Answer (score 2):

use angular [foreach](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.forEach) loop.

```
var values = {name: 'misko', gender: 'male'};
var log = [];
angular.forEach(values, function(value, key) {
   this.push(key + ': ' + value);
}, log);
```

Answer (score 0):

Example of for each in angular js

```
var values = {name: 'misko', gender: 'male'};
var log = [];
angular.forEach(values, function(value, key) {
   this.push(key + ': ' + value);
}, log);
```

Refer [angular docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.forEach) for more